# Manual rotate cassandra system.log

Tags: cassandra

Is there any way to force manual rotation in a cassandra system.log?
I need to have a new system.log created every day at 0:00 (in a cron).

Initially I tried a basic mv, but the cassandra stops writing in the log file if it does not do a service restart

```
LOG_NAME="system.log.`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M"`"
LOG_PATH="/var/log/cassandra"
mv ${LOG_PATH}/system.log ${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_NAME}  &&  '' > ${LOG_PATH}/system.log && chown cassandra:cassandra ${LOG_PATH}/system.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found!

```
apt-get install -y logrotate
```

Edit file: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate

Add the line:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/cassandra/logrotate.conf
```

Create the file: /etc/cassandra/logrotate.conf
And Add:

```
/var/log/cassandra/system.log {
rotate 365
copytruncate
compress
}
```

To manual execute:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/cassandra/logrotate.conf
```

Additionally, I can increase the size of the cassandra system.log in logback.xml, only to not do the rotate so many times a day by changing the line:

```
<MaxFileSize> 100MB </ maxFileSize>
```